# What is the meaning of "Светло мне"?

Tags: значения

I'm trying to learn russian, I would like to know what "светло мне" means. The complete phrase is: "Даже тёмной ночью светло мне".

Comment: Even when it's dark it is light to me.

Answer (score 7):

"Светло" itself is an impersonal construction in the line with "Холодно", "Сыро", "Грязно", "Жарко" etc. Yet together with dative case it rather means *a particular person feels* that.

```
"Плохо" - It is bad
"Ему плохо" - He feels bad
```

Next, "*Мне светло*" is a kind of common poetical trope which even if may be read straight (Even in the dark night it's light to me) anyway sounds like "*I feel peaceful*" or something like that. And one more "musical" example to show that:

```
Отчего, отчего, отчего мне так светло,
Оттого, что ты идёшь по переулку.
...
Отчего, отчего, отчего так хорошо,
Оттого, что ты мне просто улыбнулась.
```

Answer (score 1):

"Светло мне" означает, что у этого человека "светло на душе", то есть он испытывает чувство радости и душевный подъём даже тёмной ночью.

"Светло мне" means that this person "is light on the soul", that is, he feels a sense of joy and elation in the darkest of nights.